# making a supplication to Lord

Tags: clauses

While making a prayer to Lord for oneself, does the following structure sound best?

> Lord, may I get success!

---

And how does the following differ from the one mentioned above?

> Lord, help me get success!

Comment: @Jason Bassford  What is the usual sentence construction of praying by the way?

Comment: Another issue - in English we can talk *to* 'Lord' or 'God': 'Lord/God, may I/help me get success'. We can also talk *about* God: 'making a supplication to God'. But we can only talk *about* 'the Lord': making a supplication to *the* Lord'.

Comment: There is no "usual sentence construction" for prayer. It all depends on who you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your question can have no objective answer. Different people pray in different ways, so there can't be a form that everybody agrees is *best*.

---

The semantics between your two sentences can be explained, however.

> 1. Lord, may I get success!

This is a simple request to find yourself successful.

It has the *implication* of asking the Lord to arrange things in order to make it occur.

In mundane terms, it *could* be described as having the equivalent function of the phrase "please pass me the butter." There, you are asking for somebody else to do something on your behalf. (So you don't have to reach across the table yourself.)

> 2. Lord, help me get success.

This *can* have the same interpretation as the first sentence. But there is a more subtle emphasis on having help provided rather than the thing itself.

If I continue the butter analogy, it would be the same as "please help steady my arm so that I can pick up the butter myself."

In short, it may be more about wanting assistance for something you don't think you can do entirely on your own—but still wanting to be the ultimate agent of the thing yourself.

---

Assuming that you ascribe that kind of difference in meaning to the two sentences (and it's not a given that there is any such intention), it still doesn't mean that one is a better way of praying than the other.

In general terms, most people who pray believe that the specific words are relatively unimportant. What matters is what's in your heart, and the belief that your wishes and desires will be understood even if you don't express them exactly *the right* way. Or, looked at differently, the words themselves don't matter—so there is nothing *wrong* or *right* when it comes to the phrasing chosen.